# Youtube App - Safe Search API/lock down setting

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, samsung-mobile, airwatch

Is there a way to lock the Safe Search setting in the YouTube App to always be on?  We have elementary school students and want them to use the App but cannot allow it to be used if the student can turn Safe Search off in the App.  We use Airwatch MDM but cannot find any way in the App or MDM to lock down this setting.  We are using Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look around the AirWatch Browser ? I don't know it well but you should be able to configure it with SafeSearch (or something similar). That way, your students will only use that secure browser and not the youtube app or the device browser